# Adjustable circle in GUI

Tags: java, applet, awt, keylistener, java-2d

I am trying to write an applet program in which a circle is drawn. The size of circle will increase if i press L and decrease if I press S.

```
import java.applet.Applet; 
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class oval extends Applet implements KeyListener{

    private int d=10;
    @Override
    public void init() {
        setSize(500,500);
        addKeyListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawOval(100, 100, d, d);
    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {   
    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyChar()=='L')
            d=d+5;    
        else if(e.getKeyChar()=='S')
            d=d-5;
        repaint();
    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: What problem you are having with this code? Does it not not compile/throw exception/gives bad results?

Comment: Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting editing form.

Comment: When i am executing the code,a circle is drawn in the frame but once i am pressing 'L' or 'S',the size of the circle is not changing...Why so???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Sorry, i didn't read your code completely... You were infact using KeyEvent right but when you are comparing the chars you need to do lowercase l not uppercase:

```
if(e.getKeyChar() == 'l')

not

if(e.getKeyChar() == 'L')  //this will work if the user presses Shift+l
```

I just showed you another way of doing it, the way i have it set up will work for both lowercase l and uppercase l. So it isn't case sensitive.

You were not properly using KeyEvent to trigger the certain key. Here is your code tested and working:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class oval extends Applet implements KeyListener
{
    private int d=10;

    @Override
    public void init() 
    {
        setSize(500,500);
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawOval(100, 100, d, d);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_L)
            d=d+5;    
        else if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_S)
            d=d-5;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
    {

    }
}
```

I removed the error you were throwing through keyReleased event because i have no idea why that was there...

Comment: The problem remains the same.When my applet starts executing i get a circle then i press 'l' or 's' but there is no change in size.Can anyone explain me why the size of circle is not increasing or decreasing :(

Comment: @ShwetaShaw You must be doing something wrong, because if you copied the above code provided it will compile and run just fine, as you specified. Pressing l will increase the size and s will decrease.